# Invalid character error message in javascript while trying to retrieve session storage data

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-variables

I think I've been looking at my code too long.  I keep getting the error:  **SCRIPT 1014:  Invalid character line 271, character 9**  but I can't locate the bug.
Here's the code:

```
    alert('already set');
    data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.ruletypes);
    if (data !=null)  {
        $.each(data, function(i) {
              $('#ruletypes')
                      .append($("<option></option>")
                  .attr("value",this.id)
                  .text(this.name)); 
        }); //end .each                             
    }//end if               

    vdata = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.voicecontacttypes);
    if (vdata !=null) {
            $.each(vdata, function(i) {
            $('#contact_types')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",this.id)
                    .text(this.description)); 
            }); //end .each                             
    }//end if
```

The line it's dying on is where I'm assigning a value to vdata: (line 271)

```
vdata = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.voicecontacttypes);
```

From what I can see, the code for vdata is the same as for data... and I am able to successfully populate the ruletypes select control ...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I've updated my code that sets the variables to look like this:

```
$.getJSON(
    url = someurl,
    function(data)  {
          sessionStorage.setItem("voicecontacttypes", data); 
          data = $.parseJSON(data); //converting to a javascript object vs. just string....
         console.log("======== voice contact types start =============");           

                 console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("voicecontacttypes"));
             console.log("======== voice contact types stop =============");
```

etc...

and here's the output in the debug window in IE 9:

```
LOG: ======== voice contact types start ============= 
LOG: [{"id":"2","name":"ll","description":"Land Line","objecttype":"3"},{"id":"3","name":"mobile","description":"Mobile Phone","objecttype":"3"},{"id":"6","name":"pager","description":"Pager","objecttype":"2"}] 
LOG: ======== voice contact types stop =============
```

And now the code to retrieve this data looks like this:

```
alert('already set');
console.log("===== getting session data start ======")
data = sessionStorage.getItem("voicecontacttypes");
console.log(data);
console.log("===== getting session data stop ======");
if (data !=null) {
        $.each(data, function(i) {
        $('#contact_types')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",this.id)
                .text(this.description)); 
        }); //end .each                             
}//end if
```

Here's the debug data in the console:

```
LOG: ===== getting session data start ====== 
LOG: [{"id":"2","name":"ll","description":"Land Line","objecttype":"3"},{"id":"3","name":"mobile","description":"Mobile Phone","objecttype":"3"}{"id":"6","name":"pager","description":"Pager","objecttype":"2"}] 
LOG: ===== getting session data stop ======
```

As you can see, I've implemented the suggestion to use get / setItem(). 
And you can see that the data is preserved correctly in the session. 
However, now I'm getting the following error message:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'text'
```

This error is happening where I'm trying to loop through $('#contact_types')

Comment: have you tried to `console.log(vdata)`?

Comment: I'm guessing `sessionStorage.voicecontacttypes` isn't valid JSON.

Comment: In general, you should be using the `.getItem()` and `.setItem()` methods of browser `Storage`, as they are consistent and actually standard. Property access works, but can't with polyfills

Comment: And how about removing extra `)` from here `.text(this.name));`? And from `.text(this.description)); ` also

Comment: u_mulder, that's not an extra ).  It closes off the append...

Comment: Ah, ok, you're right.

Comment: Derek, I've taken your suggestion and am using getItem() and setItem()

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.
I have to convert the data back to a json object before I can loop through it.

```
data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("voicecontacttypes"));
```